# 401 instead of 403 with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-401, spring-boot-2

With *[Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) 1.5.6.RELEASE* I was able to send HTTP Status code `401` instead of `403` as described in [How let spring security response unauthorized(http 401 code) if requesting uri without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801468/how-let-spring-security-response-unauthorizedhttp-401-code-if-requesting-uri-w), by doing this:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //...
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("myHeader"));
        //...
    }
}
```

using the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint` class.

I just upgraded to [*Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE*](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/01/spring-boot-2-0-goes-ga) and found there is not such class any more (at least in that package).

**Questions:**

- Does this class (`Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint`) exist yet in Spring Boot?
- If no, what could be a good alternative for keeping the same behavior in an existing project in order to keep consistency with other implementations which depend on this status code (`401`) instead of `403`?

---

Please notice this is different from [Spring Security anonymous 401 instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643029/spring-security-anonymous-401-instead-of-403) because it's referring specifically to SpringBoot **2** (there are solutions in that post not applicable anymore in SpringBoot version 2 or others are not needed at all)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security anonymous 401 instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643029/spring-security-anonymous-401-instead-of-403)

Comment: @Leponzo, thanks for pointing this out. I think it shouldn't be considered a duplicate and added a comment on the original post explaining why -- for future readers. I did find an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52986942/5640649) very similar to the one I posted below -- but it was actually posted after mine :) ... anyways, in a broader scope, I think they're different questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Heads up

**By default** Spring Boot 2 will return **`401`** when `spring-boot-starter-security` is added as a dependency and an unauthorized request is performed.

This may change if you place some custom configurations to modify the security mechanism behavior. If that's the case and you truly need to force the `401` status, then read the below original post.

### Original Post

The class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint` was removed in favor of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint`.

In my case the code would go like this:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //...
        http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
        //...
    }
}
```

**Bonus**

If you need to return some information in the response body or customize the response somehow you can do something like this:

1- Extend `AuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
public class MyEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private final HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private final Object responseBody;

    public MyEntryPoint(HttpStatus httpStatus, Object responseBody) {
        Assert.notNull(httpStatus, "httpStatus cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(responseBody, "responseBody cannot be null");
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.responseBody = responseBody;
    }

    @Override
    public final void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(httpStatus.value());

        try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {
            writer.print(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseBody));
        }
    }
}
```

2- Provide an instance of `MyEntryPoint` to the security configuration

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // customize your response body as needed
        Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        responseBody.put("error", "unauthorized");

        //...
        http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, responseBody));
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now bad credential requests are returning 401, but empty-body response. Also, unauthorized requests, which should return 403, are also returning 401 with empty-body response.

Comment: This returns 401s with no body. That's fine for js, but when viewed in Firefox it's a blank page and when viewed in Chrome it says "This page isn't working". It's easy to make your own replacement of the Htp401AuthenticationEntryPoint though and use that. Just implement AuthenticationEntryPoint and set whatever status and message you want.

Comment: @Planky thank you very much for pointing that out! I just put a possible approach others might follow based on your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate @lealceldeiro's answer:

Before Spring Boot 2 my Securiy Configuration class looked like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint securityException401EntryPoint() {
      return new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("Bearer realm=\"webrealm\"");
    }

    @Autowired
    private Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntrypoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      // some http configuration ...

      // Spring Boot 1.5.x style
      http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntrypoint);
    }
//...
}
```

And now in Spring Boot 2 it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Bean configuration for Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint can be removed

    //Autowiring also removed

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      // some http configuration ...

      // Spring Boot 2 style
      http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }
//...
}
```

See also this [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10715#issuecomment-363592444) in *Spring Boot Github Repo* > *PR Remove Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint*.

Comment: The solution looks nice and clean, but it is missing the mandatory `WWW-Authenticate` Header, which would tell the client how he can attempt to authenticate

Answer (score 2):

[`Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) was removed.

See *Spring Boot Github Repo* > Issue [#10715](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10715) (Remove Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint):

> **Remove Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint**
>
> rwinch commented on 20 Oct 2017
>   As far as I can tell it is not being used in the Spring Boot code base, so it might be good to remove `Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Depending on your requirements, you could use:

- [HttpStatusEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/HttpStatusEntryPoint.html)
- [BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.html)

Comment: Thanks, very useful link from spring boot git repo. In the answer I provided future readers can see how I used `HttpStatusEntryPoint` according to my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For reactive (WebFlux) stack you can override the returned status code by adding such @Bean to catch some specific exceptions:

```
@Component
class MyErrorAttributes : DefaultErrorAttributes() {
override fun getErrorAttributes(
    request: ServerRequest,
    options: ErrorAttributeOptions
): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val cause = super.getError(request)

    val errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(request, options)

    when (cause) {
        is TokenExpiredException -> {
            errorAttributes["status"] = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()
            errorAttributes["error"] = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.reasonPhrase
        }
    }

    return errorAttributes
}
}
```

Comment: Nice! What's the syntax from?

Comment: it is Kotlin language

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your logic with overriding the class AuthenticationEntryPoint
this should be working:

```
@Component public class AuthEntryPointException implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write("{\"result\":\"UNAUTHORIZED\",\"message\":\"UNAUTHORIZED or Invalid Token\"}");
    }
}
```