# HTTP 401 on AccessDeniedException

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security

I have the following security config and JwtFilter:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig(
    val tokenService: TokenService,
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(), WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(
                JwtFilter(authenticationManager(), tokenService),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
    }
}

class JwtFilter(
    authManager: AuthenticationManager,
    private val tokenService: TokenService,
) : BasicAuthenticationFilter(authManager) {

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        req: HttpServletRequest,
        res: HttpServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val header = req.getHeader("Authorization")
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res)
            return
        }
        tokenService.extractUser(header)?.also {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = it
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res)
    }
}
```

**`TokenService#extractUser` throws an `AccessDeniedException` in case of JWT parsing errors. I can't find a way to map it to HTTP 401. Can it be done?**

I have tried using `HttpSecurity#exceptionHandling()` as well as adding an `@ExceptionHandler` inside a `@ControllerAdvice`, but I am always getting HTTP 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241384/401-instead-of-403-with-spring-boot-2) thread I managed to solve it by adding the following two lines to my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure`:

```kotlin
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
```